# Facebook Graph API Getting Photo Album Cover

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the album cover photo using:

```
$facebook->api("/{ALBUM_ID}/picture", "get");
```

but if I use the above code I get nothing to return, and if I try using it with the Open Graph API explorer on Facebook, it just sits there with the loading graphic.

If I access it from my browser, I do get a return image.

Does the call above not return an image URL? If not, what does it return and how do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `/{album_id}/picture` field listed in the API for an album, but it does seem to work the same way as it does for users, pages, etc.

Note that most places in the API where `/{object ID}/picture` is documented and supported, it returns a HTTP 301 redirect to the photo, suitable for embedding directly into an `<img src=''/>` tag, so it won't work in most code or in the Graph API Explorer.

For albums, that does work, but probably isn't what you want because you'd need to embed the access token in the URL used in the `img` tag

For this case (and other similar cases), you can request `/{album_id}?fields=picture` and get back the URL of the cover photo instead of a redirect to it

Comment: Oh I see. I was reading the documentation wrong then. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Is there anyway to get a square or small size using your method?